# How can this code return an Index Out Of Range error

Tags: vb.net

The log files client has sent to me on the stack trace are showing a Index Out of Range exception when accessing this method but this is the code I have around it, Is it still even possible for this code to throw index out of range errors?

```
If Not med Is Nothing AndAlso med.Any() Then
    If med(0).Id = 0 AndAlso med(0).StatusId = 0 Then
        Return True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Given that you are not showing what `med` is, yes, it is entirely possible.

Comment: Definitely need to know what `med` is.

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: @GSerg : But aren't we checking to make sure _medsData is not null and with .Any() checking to make sure it at least has one item in it ?  ( it is a Collection of meds)

Comment: @KSNoob Please just show how `med` is defined. If you are wondering, a) `med` can be a collection that is not zero-based, b) `med` can be an object with a default property that does not accept `0` c) `med` can be a collection indexed by strings and you have `option strict off`, d) `med` can be a sequence that does not return same elements when enumerated another time.

Comment: And apparently you have item `a)` because [`Collection` is one-based](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.100).aspx#Zero-Based%20and%20One-Based%20Collections). Please look into `List(Of T)` instead. What wonders me though is how it went to the client given that this code would never work with `Collection`.

Comment: Sorry I meant tot type LIST, not Collection ...  Private _med As List(Of Meds) = Nothing

Comment: a) Which line generates the error? b) Is `med.Any()` a fancy way of writing `med.Count > 0`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton : Log file doesn't show the exact line number. Just from the stack trace it says this is the last method in the stack that got called.  and yes .Any() return True if there is any item in the list ... Is faster than Count because it doesn't have to fully count the number of items.

Comment: @KSNoob `Count` is instant on a `List` because `List` stores the count. And no, if med is a `List(Of T)` and `Any()` is `True` and the list is not changed from another thread, it will not throw on `med(0)`.

Comment: @KSNoob Can you confirm that you are using [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  yes Strict an Explicit are both on

Comment: At this point I think maybe their production code is just a bit older than our code base , requesting the DLL so I can decompile and see what code they got in there !